# Using RestSharp to verify server certificate and send client certificate

Tags: ssl, tls1.2, restsharp, x509certificate2, mtls

I'm writing a sample C# code to implement mTLS authentication with RestSharp.

Here is my code

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using RestSharp;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            X509Certificate2 clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(@"..\Certificate.crt"); 

            var client = new RestClient("https://apiurl:port"); 
            client.ClientCertificates = new X509CertificateCollection { clientCertificate };

            var request = new RestRequest("/testresource", Method.POST); 

            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ValidateServerCertificate;

            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Request successful");
                Console.WriteLine("Response content: " + response.Content);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Request failed with status code: " + response.StatusCode);
                Console.WriteLine("Error message: " + response.ErrorMessage);
            }
    }

private static bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
    {
        // No SSL policy errors, the certificate is considered valid
        return true;
    }

    // Check if any errors in the certificate chain
    if (chain == null || chain.ChainStatus == null)
    {
        // Certificate chain is not available or invalid
        return false;
    }

    // Check each chain status
    foreach (X509ChainStatus status in chain.ChainStatus)
    {
        if (status.Status != X509ChainStatusFlags.NoError)
        {
            // There is an error in the certificate chain, so it's considered invalid
            return false;
        }
    }


    // If we've reached here, the certificate chain is valid, but SSL policy errors are present
    // If you want to accept certificates with SSL policy errors, uncomment the line below
    //return true;

    // Otherwise, we consider the certificate invalid if SSL policy errors are present
    return false;
}

}
```

When I execute the client, I get the below error.

"The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel"

However same request is working via Postman.

Can anyone suggest what could I be doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

> X509Certificate2 clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(@"..\Certificate.crt");

your certificate doesn't contain associated private key. You cannot do certificate-base authentication using only public part of the certificate. Files that contain both, public certificate and private key often have `.pfx` or `.p12` file extension and often require password to decrypt the private key.

If your file contains both, public certificate and private key in RFC 7468 format (PEM-encoded), you may need to use [X509Certificate.CreateFromPem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.createfrompem?view=net-8.0#system-security-cryptography-x509certificates-x509certificate2-createfrompem(system-readonlyspan((system-char)))) factory method.

Comment: Hi @Crypt32
Thank you for your feedback.
<br/>

I have below files with me for the certificates.

hostname.crt
hostname.public.key.pem
hostname_cert_key.pem
hostname_keystore.p12
hostname.private.key.pem
hostname-ca-chain.cert.pem

I do not have a password though.

I tried to use X509Certificate.CreateFromPem factory method to generate the certificate from .p12 file. 

However the compiler says "'X509Certificate2' does not contain a definition for 'CreateFromPem'"

Can you please guide me to a code that uses the associated private key?

Thanks again.